How to implement onFragmented that is sent from server websocket java? (org.java_websocket.Websocket)
source: https://javadoc.io/static/org.java-websocket/Java-WebSocket/1.5.7/org/java_websocket/client/WebSocketClient.html#sendFragmentedFrame(org.java_websocket.enums.Opcode,java.nio.ByteBuffer,boolean)
I have a project that requires to send files over websocket protocol. To ease the traffic, the file is chunked into bytes (precisely 10 KB) and send over to the client chunk by chunk. My question is, how do I use the onFragmented method that is stated on the javadoc? I don't see any implementation of that method. Thankyou.
On my client side, the method that handle my incoming data that is sent by server is :
    @Override
    public void onMessage(ByteBuffer message) {
        try {
                byte[] data = new byte[message.remaining()];
            logger.info("Received : " + message.remaining());
                message.get(data);

                fos.write(data);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("error occured during receiving file");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

While the server code:
conn.sendFragmentedFrame(Opcode.BINARY, byteBuffer, isLastChunk);
But since my server also sent the isLastChunk, my client should be able to read this isLastChunk as well (the isLastChunk is necessary because this tells whether the stream must be close or not and other process). Must I use onFragmented method to be able to receive it? But how?
